# Enterprise library Validation block

Tags: enterprise-library

I have a web application project. I want to add Configuration Source and keep Validation block, Caching and Logging config files separate. But as soon as I go to the UI of enterprise Lib and add a configuration Source, it combines everything in a single file. Is there a way to separate all these ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can separate the configuration files. This [article gives](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=65) some directions.